# Bootstrap 3 button within input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to style an email input with the button inside the input box.

[image]

I can style it by writing a bunch of css that overrides bootstrap css, but was wondering if there was a way to keep within bootstrap conventions.

Comment: if you do it that way, your text could potentially be behind the button. Are you sure about that

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups input groups is what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah that's a great point. I didn't even consider that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that if you do it that way your text will go behind the button.

Have a look at bootstrap input groups. It should give you an idea on how to do it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups